# EditText and Button above TabLayout

Tags: android

I have an EditText and send button positioned above a TabLayout in XML.

- Is it possible to make it so that by default, the EditText and send button are not visible, but when the user clicks on certain buttons, it appears?
- The user should be able to keep the EditText open and scroll through the screen that the EditText is on top of.
- This should be possible to do in any of the tabs.

When I tried it previously, it was possible for the user to see and click RecyclerView items behind the EditText though I set the EditText background to white.

Representation of what I am trying to do:

[By default, the EditText and send button are hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMDGl.jpg)

[When the user clicks "Reply", the EditText and send button appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZtrB.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the replies so far. I'm trying to figure out how to communicate between the fragments and the activity. The XML for the EditText, send button, and TabLayout are in the same XML file. The activity inflates this XML file but the fragments need to be able to set the visibility of the XML file that the activity inflates.

Hopefully, I will understand once I go through this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood exactly what you want...

- You can set the visibility of any View with .setVisibility and choose Invisible/Visible/Gone
  Set the visibility of the views to Invisible in OnCreate and in one button clicked set the visibility to Visible.
- you have two options, you can align the TextView to the top of the screen.
  But the one I prefer is to put the things the user need to scroll in ScrollView and the EditText outside the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of both EditText and send button to INVISIBLE in xml something like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    ...
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<Button 
   android:id="@+id/send_button"
   ...
   android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Then when clicks on certain buttons, put it visible again:

```
EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send_button);
someButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the first question:**

1. Put the EditText and the Send Button into a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.
2. Set the layout visibility gone or invisible.
3. Override the specific button onClickListener and set the layout visibility into visible in that function

**For the second question:**

You can overlap 2 layout like this, if that is what you want to do.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

</LinearLayout>
```

The ScrollView is the main layout, it can be RecyclerView also as you mentioned.
You can put the EditText and the Button into the LinearLayout

**For the third question:**

It should work on every Tabs